# How to determine in which table row <tr> the keyup event is triggered?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a long table (10,000 rows, 10 columns) that can be edited on screen. After editing, the changes can be saved. Since I do not want to re-save the entire table I want to keep track of the rows where changes have been made. Each row-tag has a unique id as well as the table-tag. But using .keyup only functions with $('table') and not with $('tr') or $('td') and always returns the is of the table-tag. Here's a short example of my html-code:

```
    <table id="table1" contenteditable="true">
      <tr id="tr1"><td>Cell 11</td><td>Cell 12</td><td>Cell 13</td></tr>
      <tr id="tr2"><td>Cell 21</td><td>Cell 22</td><td>Cell 23</td></tr>
    </table>
```

And in jQuery I've tried several things like:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('table').keyup(function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
      });
    });
```

This always results in 'table1'. How can I get 'tr1', 'tr2', etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e.target` to see the element that originated the event and then use `.closest("tr")` to go up the parent hierarchy from there to get the row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').keyup(function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).closest("tr").attr("id"));
  });
});
```

FYI, you won't be able to get any key events in your table until you put something in the table that can accept focus (like an `<input>` tag).

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1j7vkfma/

Comment: Putting the table full of input-tags doesn't seem very attractive to me!

Comment: But why does the .click function give the desired answer and not the .keyup?

Comment: @Arnold - Your HTML, as you have it, won't accept focus and won't get keyup events.  I just put the input tags in there because you asked about keyup events and you have to have something that accepts focus in order to get keyup events in a cell.  You can obviously make the HTML whatever you want, but you asked about keyup events so I had to make something that would get keyup events so I could test my proposed solution.  I don't understand what you're asking about `.click`?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention the .click before, but I had tried that one instead of the .keyup, and it worked well. By the way I also forgot to mention the I made the table contentEditable so that's why I thought it could indeed accept focus...